# Why is "hammock" spelled the way it is?

Tags: etymology, orthography, loanwords, spanish

The word *hammock* comes from Spanish *hamaca*.

> type of hanging bed, 1650s, alteration of *hamack, hamaca* (1550s), from Spanish *hamaca*, from Arawakan (Haiti) word apparently meaning "fish nets" (compare Yukuna *hamaca*, Taino *amaca*). - *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hammock)*

It could have been natural to write *hamac* in English. Why is it written as *hammock* instead of *hamac*?

For example, double consonants indicate that the vowel before it is short. The "mm" in "hammock" also does the same thing. But there are exceptions to this. Words like "habit" still pronounce the "a" with the short "a" sound although it is written with a single "b".

Comment: *Hummock* is also spelled with two *M*s (and the first vowel is also changed out sometimes so it reads hammock or hommock).

Comment: There's lots of 2-syllable words ending in -ock: hummock, bullock, hillock, mattock, buttock, bollock, etc. Almost certainly an influence.

Comment: The OED gives the following forms of the word *hammock*:   α. 1500s–1800s hamaca, 1600s hamacca, hamacco, hamackoe, hammacho, 1700s hamacoe, 1700s–1800s hammacoe. β. 1600s hamack(e, hammac(k, hammaque, amack, hamock, hammok, 1700s hammoc, 1700s–1800s hamac, 1600s– hammock.

Comment: So the Spanish spelling was used when it was first adapted into English, but people forgot that it was a Spanish word while English spelling was still in flux (in the 17th and 18th centuries). So the spelling that was eventually settled on was not influenced by Spanish.

Comment: @PeterShor Sounds like it's worth a write-up; many of us poorer relations on the site don't have access to OED.

Comment: No, it would not have been natural to write _hamac_ in English. Final _-c_ is rare in English, apart from the Greek-derived suffix _-ic_.

Comment: I still don't see where the H came from. Spanish had no /h/ at that point; though it was spelled here and there, mostly before initial vowels, it was never pronounced. So how did the H get transcribed, if the Spanish couldn't hear it? It's still spelled that way in Spanish, but it's still not pronounced. It's /a'maka/ and it hasn't ever been pronounced with an /h/ in Spanish. Howcum it is in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED gives the early forms of the spelling of *hammock*:

> α. 1500s–1800s hamaca, 1600s hamacca, hamacco, hamackoe, hammacho, 1700s hamacoe, 1700s–1800s hammacoe. β. 1600s hamack(e, hammac(k, hammaque, amack, hamock, hammok, 1700s hammoc, 1700s–1800s hamac, 1600s– hammock.

So it looks like for the first hundred years or so, *hammock* was spelled very much like the Spanish *hamaca*.

However, English spelling was not at all consistent at that time; people spelled words how they sounded. Spelling didn't become fixed until some time in the 1700s, and by then, *hammock* was an English word—clearly the pronunciation had changed to drop the last syllable, and presumably the stress had changed to the first syllable. Since probably most people had forgotten by then that the word was originally Spanish, the eventual spelling that was settled on had no Spanish influence.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an interesting explanation regarding the origin and the adoption of the spelling of *hammock*. It is suggested that the term *hamaca* was misapplied by Columbus and his sailors which was intended for the native trees where the hammocks were hung, in the Caribbean (some sources suggest the Bahamas<sup>[*](https://books.google.es/books?id=TMvw50hrXWwC&pg=PA18&dq=columbus%20hammock%20bahamas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj93sL5s8T4AhXD3YUKHbXNB54Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=columbus%20hammock%20bahamas&f=false)</sup>, some suggest Haiti<sup>[*](https://books.google.es/books?id=QrQ5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=columbus%20hamaca&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib-sPtsMT4AhXB4YUKHQuzDZ8Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=columbus%20hamaca&f=false)</sup>, some suggest Fernandina island<sup>[*](https://books.google.es/books?id=q_pbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT47&dq=columbus%20hamaca&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib-sPtsMT4AhXB4YUKHQuzDZ8Q6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=columbus%20hamaca&f=false)</sup>) where they discovered it. These sleeping nets were used by the indigenous people called the [Taíno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%C3%ADno) and the [Arawak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arawak). It is added that Bartram and his colleagues adapted the spelling *hommock*, then it changed to *hammock*.

Here is the relevant excerpt:

> "Hammock, hommock, or hummock?" queried R. M. Harper in 1905; his answer was one of many attempts by botanists to reduce confusion over the classification of southeastern plant communities. Harper (1905) concluded that a hummock is a geographic feature, a rounded knoll, whereas "hammock" and "hommock" are synonyms for dense, hardwood forests that occur in limited areas amid the wet prairies, marshes, and pine forests of the coastal plain.
>
> The etymoloogy of "hammock" and "hommock" is obscure (Oxford English Dictionary 1933). Columbus' sailors learned to use net "hammocks," hanging beds, from
> Caribbean Indians; perhaps they misapplied the Arawak term, hamacas, intended for the woods in which the sleeping nets were hung. Bartram (1791) and other early expositors of Florida's natural history employed the "hommock" spelling, perhaps in keeping with native pronunciation, but "hammock" became the prevalent form in
> the writings of the twentieth century.
>
> <sub>The ecology of hydric hammocks: a community profile 
>
> Biological Report 85(7.26) 
>
> By: Susan W. Vince, Stephen R. Humphrey, and Robert W. Simons 
>
> https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/70110600</sub>

Here is a relevant sketch I've found from the book *[Columbus and His First Voyage: A History in Documents](https://books.google.es/books?id=iVESDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&dq=columbus%20hammock%20origin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij78Grr8T4AhUS_4UKHbqYDaIQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (edited by James E. Wadsworth):

[image]

---

Additional good read about the word hammock and its origin: 
<sub>'Hammock,' 'Hommock' or 'Hummock'? 

Author(s): Roland M. Harper 

Source: Science , Sep. 29, 1905, New Series, Vol. 22, No. 561 (Sep. 29, 1905), pp. 400-402 

Published by: American Association for the Advancement of Science 

Stable URL: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1633491</sub>